# Microsft Exchange 2013 on Server 2012 OWA shows blank page

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

I have a standard Server 2012 installed and installed Exchange 2013 onto it. On the RDP I can access OWA and it shows me the mailbox for the user currently logged in.

When I navigate my browser to my `domain.fancy/owa` from an external computer I just get a blank page in Chrome and Forbidden in IE.

If I try the ECP I get a server error. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Ensure that OWA is setup in IIS to accept connections from the outside, and ensure that you have no firewalls in the way.

Comment: Yea I can access it on the server. Using IE it gives me forbidden page. I host other sites and they are fine. If i atry ECP i get server errors displayed. yellow pages of death from external. Internal is OK  but i would like external access. cant tell what the problem is as no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with various other post on the internet.

You have to disable SSL if you don't have HTTPS certificates. It tries to redirect the login to `https://youserver.com` and fails. That is why I got weird server errors, and forbidden.

Untick `Require SSL` on the `Default Website` and click `Apply`

[image]

<sup>It is best to get a SSL certificate if you running business or production.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my IE issues logging into Exchange 2013 OWA by adding the domain to the trusted sites list in IE, however I have not had any success determining why I get a blank page after logging into Google Chrome.  I do not have an issue with Mozilla firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Just make to match the SSL Certificate in the Default Web site and in the "Exchange back end" site, this happens when you set a new certificate to services (IIS) but the change does not replicate into the "exchange back end" site so you have to do it manually.

Here's a Detailed "How To" in my blog: http://mcsemessaging.blogspot.mx/2014/12/blank-screen-after-login-via-owa-in.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a log of documentation and causes for this issue.

One work around for me was to follow the advice in [this redit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/4w63xs/exchange_2013_owa_blank_after_login_ecp_works/) and this [microsoft.com/forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/124dad6f-964a-423e-9264-23642c033650/exchange-2013-owa-blank-page-ecp-works?forum=exchangesvrclients)

Set to `disabled` the following link.

```
chrome://flags/#disable-javascript-harmony-shipping
```

[image]

This works in google chrome

You could also try the detailed instructions on this following links.
These detail steps to ensure the correct bindings and ssl certificates are being used on the sites.

https://www.systoolsgroup.com/updates/ecp-owa-blank-white-page-after-login/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079905/why-ms-exchange-2013-owa-stuck-in-loading-not-able-to-open
https://bobcares.com/blog/owa-blank-page-after-login/